# How to compile with an another libC on Linux? (gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, libc

I want to compile my C program with an another C library like dietlibc or musl.

What gcc option should I use for this purpose?

Comment: `man gcc`, search for libraries (you can do this in google or on your system)

Answer (score 4):

> What gcc option should I use for this purpose?

You should read `dietlibc` or `musl` documentation. Example for `dietlibc` from [here](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/FAQ.txt):

```
diet gcc -pipe -g -o t t.c
```

That is: `dietlibc` provides a wrapper command called `diet` which takes care of this for you.

Example for `musl` from [here](https://www.musl-libc.org/how.html):

```
musl-gcc -static -Os hello.c
```

That is, `musl` provides a wrapper command called `musl-gcc` which takes care of this for you.

You can examine `musl-gcc` and `diet` to see exactly what options they pass the to the linker. Note however that the exact options may change from version to version, and you are better off *always* using the wrappers even if you know exactly which flags they pass.

Comment: If you actually look inside these scripts, the "take care" part is generally done by providing the correct ld scripts to link it with their respective libraries. Would be good, if OP actually gets to read that.

Comment: Can I do it _without_ the wrapper?